# Streaming results in amphp

Tags: php, stream, amphp

My goal is to create a pipeline that could have tens of thousands of items in the iterator. Since this can take a long time to process, I want to steam the results back to the client as they are produced.

This is not a web server, it is communication between two systems that I control.

I *think* I need to create a future for each item, with a closure that writes to the stream. That seems... big. I am still fiddling with that, and actually `Pipeline::tap()` might do the job.

My biggest problem, though, is how to establish the stream. It seemed like I should be able to return a `Response` to the client with a `WriteableStream` for the body, and continue to write to the stream until all the items are processed.

However, even on the server, the `Response` only accepts a `ReadableStream` as a body. To get a `WriteableStream` it seems like I need to use sockets, but by doing that I lose all the useful abstractions of `Request` and `Response`. I guess I'm unbound by all http requirements when using sockets, so I could make my own abstractions, but I'd rather not.

`http-server` is built on sockets, so it seems like this should be possible.

Any example of streaming the results of a pipeline back to the client would be super-welcome!

Here is the code I have at the moment. The stream is passed in from the request handler, in the futile hope that it can be returned with the `Response` before the pipeline completes. this iteration of my code uses `tap()`, which probably isn't how it's intended to be leveraged:

```
    $pipeline = Pipeline::fromIterable($bigList)
        ->concurrent(Router::MAX_CONCURRENT_PROCESSES_PER_REQUEST)
        ->unordered()
        ->map(fn (ListItem $item) => $this->getResultForItem($item))
        ->filter(fn (?Result $r) => $r instanceof Result);

    // if there's a stream, don't do anything here that will block until the pipeline is finished.
    if (!is_null($stream)) {
        $streamStarted = false;

        $pipeline->tap(function (Result $r) use ($stream, &$streamStarted) {

            $stream->write($streamStarted ? ',' : '[');
            $streamStarted = true;
            $stream->write(json_encode($r));

        });

        // something here to send the `end()` message when the pipeline has been completed for all items
        //$future = async()

    } else {
        foreach($pipeline as $profile) {
            $indexed[$profile->dsid] = $profile;
        }
    }
```

If I could add the WriteableStream to the response, I'd be in good shape, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is a way to open a stream and write to it as I imagined above. Instead, a `ReadableStream` can be created that will do the chore automagically.

```
$pipeline = Pipeline::fromIterable($bigList)
    ->concurrent(Router::MAX_CONCURRENT_PROCESSES_PER_REQUEST)
    ->unordered()
    ->map(fn (ListItem $item) => $this->getResultForItem($item))
    ->filter(fn (?Result $r) => $r instanceof Result);
    ->map(fn(Result $r) => json_encode($r));

$stream = new ReadableIterableStream($pipeline->getIterator());
```

That will write each `Result` object to the stream as it becomes available. The `ReadableStream` is returned in the http response, and is updated whenever the pipeline completes for an item in `$bigList`.

The client then does something like:

```
while($text = $response->getBody()->read()) {
    $response[] = json_decode($text);
}
```